# Licences, release notes and sample files?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

This is probably a stupid question, but I will ask anyway: Is it safe to delete the licences, release notes and sample files?  Is there any other file I could/should remove? I'm creating an new store with CE 1.9 and want my directory structure to be as compact as possible.

Also what is the `mage` file for? Is this needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely safe. But beware of deleting the sample files which demonstrate possibilities for .htaccess, local.xml and the like. You may need to refer to them later.

**For users of Enterprise Edition:**

If you remove the LICENSE_EE.txt file a new installation will fail. This file is required to be present at the time of install *only*. After that it can be removed

**Mage file**

This is a bash executable that interfaces with `downloader/mage.php` - this gives you the ability to download and install community modules and Magento releases / upgrades from within the shell. Removing this file wouldn't be detrimental but you would lose this ability.

**Sample files**

Sample files safe to remove are:

```
./.htaccess.sample
./errors/local.xml.sample
./index.php.sample
./php.ini.sample
./app/etc/local.xml.additional
./etc/local.xml.template
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks. Should I also delete `./etc/local.xml.template`? My local.xml is already filled out so I assume it's not necessary?

Comment: I suppose that's another candidate as well. I can add it to the answer.

Comment: That would be great.